# AD Домен перестает быть видимым через некоторое время после перезагрузки DC

Tags: windows, администрирование, active-directory, windows-2016

Есть DC.domain.com с Windows 2016.
Это сервак в интернете с белым IP.
На него еще куча всего навешано, в частности - RDS.

Три дня назад всплыла проблема: через какое-то время после перезагрузки DC домен перестает быть доступным.

DNS-запись SRV _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcsdomain.com есть как на самом DC.domain.com, так и на внешних DNS-серваках. В частности, dig _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcsdomain.com srv выдает ответом DC.domain.com откуда угодно.

Из-за того, что домен отваливается, в него нельзя завести компьютер, а старые серваки запрещают вход по RDP с диагнозом "указанный домен не существует или к нему невозможно подключиться". Иногда еще жалуются на непроверенную сеть NTLA.

Все проблемы исчезают после перезагрузки dc.domain.com, но через несколько часов (3-6 или около того) вылезают вновь.
На сам сервак по RDP под доменными учетками входить можно без проблем.
Локально на других серваках под доменными учетками пускает (хотя подозреваю, что они синхронизируются по кэшу, а не по доменному запросу).
389 порт открыт в фаерволле и слушается с 0.0.0.0

dcdiag диагностирует проблему с одним конкретным компьютером (который за семью натами), больше ничего путного не выдает.

Куда копать? И какие службы отвечают за AD-деятельность? (до разрешения проблемы хочется перезапускать службу а не весь сервер)

UPD: Перезапуск службы "Доменные Службы AD" с сопутствующими от нее зависимостями не помогает.